# Finding locus of a point P under the given conditions...

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

> The locus of a point $P(\alpha,\beta)$ moving under the condition that the line $y=\alpha x+\beta$ is a tangent to the hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$,is 
> (a) a hyperbola
> (b) a parabola
> (c) a circle 
> (d) an ellipse

What I tried...

The slope of the given line is $\alpha$, differentiating the equation of parabola and equating $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to $\alpha$,
$$\frac{x}{a^2}=\frac{y}{b^2}\frac{dy}{dx}\implies \frac{x}{a^2}=\frac{y}{b^2}\cdot (\alpha)$$
From here, I have no clue how to proceed. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

$y=\alpha x+\beta$ will be tangent to $x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2=1$ if it comapares to $y=mx+\sqrt{m^2a^2-b^2},$ we get $\alpha =m, \beta=\sqrt{m^2a^2-b^2}$. So,
$\beta^2=a^2 \alpha^2-b^2  \implies a^2\alpha^2-\beta^2=b^2$. Finally the locus of $(\alpha, \beta)$ is
$$\frac{x^2}{b^2/a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1,$$
whiuch is a hyperbola.